# PHP File Name and File Size Output

Tags: php, file, directory, filesize

How can i add a file size beside my file names using PHP???

Currently Using This:

```
<?php
# Configuration
$show_path = 0;   # Show local path.
$show_dotdirs = 1;   # Show '.' and '..'.

$path = substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], 0,
    strrpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], '/') + 1);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>

<body>
<div id="menu">
  <div id="menualign"><a href="index.php"><img src="images/home.png" onmouseover="src='images/homed.png'" onmouseout="src='images/home.png'"/></a><img src="images/moviesa.png"/><a href="tvguide.php"><img src="images/tv.png" onmouseover="src='images/tvd.png'" onmouseout="src='images/tv.png'"/></a></div>
</div>
<div id="container">
  <div id="fleft">
    <table cellspacing="1">
      <tr>
        <th><?php if ($show_path == 1) { echo $path; } else { echo 'Current Movies'; } ?></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="left"><?php
$dirs = array();
$files = array();

$dir = dir('../Movies/');
while ($entry = $dir->read()) {
    if (($entry != '.') and (substr($entry, -4) != '.php')) {
        if (is_dir($entry)) {
            if (($entry != '..') or $show_dotdirs){
                $dirs[] = $entry;
            }
        } else {
            $files[] = $entry;
        }
    }
}
$dir->close();

sort($dirs);
foreach ($dirs as $dir) {
    printf('<strong>&lt;</strong> <a href="%s">%s</a> <strong>&gt;</strong><br />' . "\n", $dir, $dir);
}

sort($files);
foreach ($files as $file) {
    printf('<hr />%s<br />' . "\n", $file, $file);
}
?></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="fright">TEST
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Which outputs as this: http://downunderpctech.com/output.png

I Would like to Add a section for Filesize

Probably using the same code but to collect filesize info as the Filename but in a new  beside it

I am not too concerned about the Filesize output, but would prefer only to output KB

Thanks, Adam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the function [`filesize`](http://php.net/filesize) on your `$file` variable.

And then you can output a human readable size with [this little function](http://snipplr.com/view/4633/):

```
function file_size($size)
{
  $filesizename = array(" Bytes", " KB", " MB", " GB", " TB", " PB", " EB", " ZB", " YB");
  return $size ? round($size/pow(1024, ($i = floor(log($size, 1024)))), 2) . $filesizename[$i] : '0 Bytes';
}
```

You define the function before the `# Configuration` and then you call it in your foreach:

```
echo file_size(filesize('../Movies/'.$file));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write the file, then use the filesize function to get the file size and rename the file with the size in the file name.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your foreach

```
echo '<span>'.round(filesize ('../Movies/'.$file)/1024, 1).' Kb</span>';
```

Comment: Ok so i have done this:


sort($files);
foreach ($files as $file) {
 if ($tick1 != 0)
 {
  echo "<hr />";
 }
    printf('%s<br />' . "\n", $file, $file);
    echo round(filesize ($file)/1024, 1).' KB<br />';
 $tick1 = $tick1 + 1;
}


And all i am getting from Every File is 0KB...